# scrollTop doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code -

```
($("div[id$='fixedDataDiv']")[0]).scrollTop(0);
```

This is called when I change tabs in IE8.

The error message I get is -

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this action
```

Is my syntax incorrect?

Comment: You are trying to apply jQuery methods on a naked DOM element - that's not gonna happen

Comment: You're missing the wrapping `$`.

Comment: @zzzzBov, that beats the purpose of having selectors

Comment: @Alexander, I'm well aware of that, however the 1 character difference is an easy miss for a jQuery n00b.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to select the first matched element you can try:

```
$("div[id$='fixedDataDiv']:first").scrollTop(0);
```

`scrollTop()` is one of jQuery object's methods, `[0]` converts the jQuery Object to a DOM element which has no `scrollTop()` method.

Comment: or `$("div[id$='fixedDataDiv']").eq(0).scrollTop(0);`